# list adapter using fragments

Tags: java, android, listadapter

I am using a listAdapter to try to populate a listView. but i am having an issue and it is causing my application to crash. i initially wanted to populate the list into xml objects but i believe a listView would be better for my application..THIS IS MY ADAPTER

```
    package com.example.victor.kidsrewards;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.List;

    /**
     * Created by Victor on 3/20/2016.
     */
    public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {

        private final Context context;

        private final List<Task> taskList;

        public ListAdapter(Context context, List<Task> taskList){
            super(context, R.layout.fragment_tasks, taskList);
            this.context = context;
            this.taskList= taskList;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasks,parent,false);

            /*TextView taskText = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.newTaskText);
            taskText.setText(taskList.get(position).getText());

            TextView pointsText = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.newPointsText);
           pointsText.setText(taskList.get(position).getText());*/

            return rowView;
        }
    }
**
```

---

**
**this is my xml code**

```
    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="TODO TEXT GOES_HERE">
    </ListView>

</FrameLayout>
**
```

---

**

**This is my fragment where i call my listadapter**

```
package com.example.victor.kidsrewards;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class TaskList extends ListFragment {

    private TaskDataBase tdb;
    public TaskList() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_task_list, container, false);

    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        tdb = new TaskDataBase(getContext());

        setListAdapter(new ListAdapter(getContext(), tdb.getTasks()));


    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);


    }
}
```

Comment: please provide the exception you get

Comment: Please post stack trace.

Comment: Where you have defined your textview layout please specify that layout also.

Comment: at this moment i dont have an exeption or a trace. I dont want to use the textview, (i have commented the textview out). instead, i want to use the listView  in fragment_tasks.xml (specified above)

Answer (score 0):

What is the name of the layout file that you have included? 
If it is fragment_tasks.xml then fragment_tasks.xml  should not have a ListView. It should at least have the textView with id newTaskText. 
Define the content layout which contains a listView. Then there is a layout for each row. This should only contain the TextView (and other views relevant to a single row) but not ListView.

Comment: Im sorry this is my first time using stackoverflow, i have just updated my question.. I dont want to use the TextViews, I only want to use the LIstView. Im not sure if i shoud reference that somewhere in my  getView method in my list dapter and remove the textView. I am also unsure of how to reference it. thank you

Comment: how can i use that rowView to populate my list?

Comment: A typical listView based UI requires two types of layouts. One is the top level layout that contains the ListView that you want to populate. The other is the layout for each row. If all the rows look alike, then it is a single row layout if not, there could be multiple row layouts. You use the first one to do setContentView in your activity. The second is the one you use in getView when you inflate a row layout.

Comment: Great insight. Thank you so much!